# How can I change my insert to update

Tags: php, mysql

This is my insert code in the php file. i want to update the data 
what should i change?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO students( name,city,age,number,password,img)
            values ( '$ename','$ecity','$eage','$enumber','$epassword','$imgname' )");
```

Comment: You read the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Use `UPDATE` query? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: The question does not show any effort.

Comment: Maybe what you really want is the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option to `INSERT`. It's explained in the `INSERT` documentation at the mysql.com web site.

Comment: `update students set name='$ename',city='$ecity',age='$eage',number='$enumber',password='$epassword',img='$imgname' where id='' ` change the last id part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a standard MySQL `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name=value, column_name2=value2 WHERE standard_where_clause
```